# Destroyed while process ("cmd")

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, cmd, qwidget

Есть программа, которая запускает несколько команд через командную строку:

```
void MainWindow::on_installButton_clicked()
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->clear();
    QString program = "cmd";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "/K" << "chcp 1251 & cd /d C:/Users/Пользователь/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts & pip install adssad";
    QProcess *Process = new QProcess(this);
    Process->start(program, arguments);
    connect(Process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [=] {
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString::fromLocal8Bit(Process->readAll()));
    });
    connect(Process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, [=] {
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString::fromLocal8Bit(Process->readAllStandardError()));
    });

}
```

При закрытии программы (даже если выполнение команд уже завершено) получаю сообщение в Debug: `Destroyed while process ("cmd") is still running.` Попробовал добавить: `Process.waitForFinished();` - из за этого программа зависает до закрытия процесса. Решил вывести всё это в отдельный поток - не работает ui внутри созданной мною функции. Как мне правильно завершить cmd без зависания программы? Или просто не обращать внимания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно дебаг говорит. хоть команды и выполнились, сам интерпретатор (cmd) вполне себе работает.
Добавьте на исполнение в cmd "exit"

```
arguments << "/K" << "chcp 1251 & cd /d C:/Users/Пользователь/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts & pip install adssad & exit";
```

Или запускайте интерпретатор с ключиком /C (с завершением после исполнения)

```
arguments << "/C" << "chcp 1251 & cd /d C:/Users/Пользователь/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts & pip install adssad";
```

И конечно же есть смысл добавить ожидание завершения (waitForFinished).